# creating triggers vs views

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a `mysql` database with the following tables:

1. `Penalties`
2. `Scores`
3. `player_instance`

When penalties is updated/deleted then it will update scores (via a trigger). Also when a `player_instance` row is deleted then (via `ON DELETE CASCADE`) the associated penalties row will be deleted. The problem is that in `mysql` the foreign key constraints do not activate triggers. Thus when `player_instance` is deleted it will delete the relevant penalties row but not update scores.

I have been thinking about ways to solve this:

1. Use a database that does support activating triggers on foreign key constraints. such as `PostgreSQL`. How difficult will it be for me to change the script from `mysql` to `PostgreSQL`?
2. I could replace the foreign key constraints with triggers (i.e. `CREATE TRIGGER ON DELETE...`). This should mean that when `player_instance` is deleted, it will trigger the deletion of `Penalties` which will in turn update `Scores`.
3. I could do away with scores entirely (which records the score in a match). Instead, I could create a `VIEW` which would sum up all the points in penalties to get the score in a match.
   Is this a bad idea for performance or design?

Any thoughts on the above, including other options would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends: how often do you query table "Penalties"?
We assume: often.

If you can, switch to PostgreSQL.
It simply works. Robust, elegant. You need to learn something new, but nothing terrible.

Point 3 means data to be recalculated every time.

Point 2 can work, but it is a workaround. Good solution if switch database is to heavy.